# align-self: flex-end won't move the game board to the bottom of the page?

Tags: css, flexbox

Hey friends I'm making a connect 4 game. I'm using a table for the board. I'm also using flexbox to position the board. I have the body set to flex, and used justify-content to center it horizontally and I thought align-items: flex-end would put it at the bottom of the page, but it's not working? Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: flex-end;
}

table {
 margin: auto;
 background-color: blue;
}

td {
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Connect Four</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="board-wrapper">
  <table>
   <tr class="row-1">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-2">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-3">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-4">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-5">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-6">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The board actually *is* at the bottom. You just need the parent to be at least the height of the viewport using `min-height: 100vh`.

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: flex-end;
        min-height: 100vh;
}

table {
 margin: auto;
 background-color: blue;
}

td {
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Connect Four</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="board-wrapper">
  <table>
   <tr class="row-1">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-2">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-3">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-4">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-5">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-6">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! 2 more questions though.  1. Why can't I just use heght: 100vh instead, and 2. How do I remove the space or gutter between the table cells?

Comment: you can use the height attribute, but using min height lets the page get bigger if you add more content or if someone is viewing it on a small screen

Comment: @Randy Remove the gutter between table cells using `table { border-collapse: collapse; }`

Comment: Oh Ok so height: 100vh; would lock it to my specific screen size? And thank you for the other answer:)

Answer (score 0):

The table is being aligned to the bottom, but the body's height is not the viewport height. Add a `height: 100vh` to the body and you'll see it.

Comment: Thank you so much!! 2 more questions though.  1. Why can't I just use heght: 100vh instead, and 2. How do I remove the space or gutter between the table cells?

Comment: I don't understand question 1, you want to use `height: 100vh` instead of what? For number 2 check the `border-collapse` property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse